# Why is my banner size still big?

Tags: html, css, banner

I´m trying to reduce total size of the banner: I have reduced the size of the picture to 50%, but still there is a white background that doesn't change. I don't want it, or want to make it the same size as picture cause it's currently too big. Following is my html code:

```
<section id="banner"></section>
```

And following CSS:

```
#banner {
    background-image:url('../images/banner-2.png');
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 14em 3em 14em;
    text-align: center;}
```

Following is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dexoey/vtdscvxk/

And here you can see how that extra white background looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u2zP.jpg

Comment: Remove or reduce this: `padding: 14em 3em 14em;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the `padding` is what that is causing you the trouble. Try to reduce it:

```
padding: 10em 3em 10em;
```

Comment: thx. it worked. I voted your right answer up. I also appreciate if you vote up my question, as I´m beginner and need score. thx again.